# How to Delete a certain sequence of elements from a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to remove a certain sequence of indexes/elements from an array

**I tried :**

```
$tobeputinfiletemp  = explode ("&", $entityBody);  
$tobeputinfilefinal         =array_slice($tobeputinfiletemp , 2, 4);
print_r($tobeputinfilefinal);
```

I was trying to remove index 2,3 and 4 from the array , but it seems like array_slice() returns the extracted indexes as a separate array , and not the remaining array after the the extraction.

How can one get the remaining array after extraction, is there any buit-in function for this?

Comment: Just reassign the result of array_slice to the original variable?

Comment: Reassign ? You mean Like this : `$tobeputinfiletemp=$tobeputinfilefinal;`

Comment: Yes, or just `$tobeputinfiletemp  = array_slice($tobeputinfiletemp , 2, 4);` directly. Or maybe I misunderstood...seems too obvious

Comment: When you say _delete_, you want to re-index the array after that or keep the index keys as is?

Comment: But that still printing the same extracted indexes and not the remaining array

Comment: @nice_dev I wanted to re-index the remaining array  , after removing the unrequited  indexes

Comment: @Sam You can just run a loop to unset all unwanted indexes.  After that, do `array_values($arr)` on your array.

Comment: Ok I see. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php might help you.

Comment: @nice_dev you are right that did the trick